# how to fade in and out 2 textview at same time in android

Tags: android

My requirement

I have to collapse and expand some views so i will use below code:
 mBinding.appbarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener((appBarLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
            Log.d(TAG,"verticalOffset"+verticalOffset);
            float percentage = (float)Math.abs(verticalOffset)/appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();

when i collapse textview one should be fade in steps of 0.9 to 0.1 and when i expand i have to make textview 2 should fade in steps of 0.1 to 0.9 and show textview 2 fully and textview 1 should fade out and be invisible and from expanded view when i try to collapse i have to fade textview 2 and fade in textview 1 in steps of 0.1 to 0.9.

Basically on collapse and expand one textview should fade in and one textview should fade out

How to achieve this?

one TextView should fade in in steps of alpha(0.1 to 0.9) same time another textview should fade out in steps of (0.9 to 0.01) and vice versa.

one textview should be fully visible in steps and other should be fade out when first textview is shown and similar when second is shown first should be fade out in steps.

How to single method for both textview to work as above 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use animatorSet.

Comment: can u provide some code ? as i mentioned single method for both the textview

Comment: i have updated my requirement.Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share screenshoot.

Comment: Okey, I understood

Comment: Because, your percentage is always 1 or 0

Comment: I wrote with Kotlin, You could covert to java

Comment: Just add these lines. You don't need animation or check expand

Comment: You should convert to double, check my code

Comment: Double.valueOf(verticalOffset) and  Double.valueOf(appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange())

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) - appBarLayout.totalScrollRange == 0) {
            Log.d("AppBar","Collapsed")
            // Collapsed
        } else if (verticalOffset == 0) {
            // Expanded
            Log.d("AppBar","Expanded")

        } else {
            // Idle
            Log.d("AppBar","Idle")
        }
```

Percentage like this:

```
val percentage =  Math.abs(verticalOffset.toDouble())/ appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toDouble()
   textView.alpha = percentage.toFloat()
   textView2.alpha = 1.0f - percentage.toFloat()
```

Check percentage wherever you want

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210103/discussion-on-answer-by-kasim-ozdemir-how-to-fade-in-and-out-2-textview-at-same).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a method to fade Views in and out.
Here is a simple example using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator)'s [alphaBy(float value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#scaleXBy(float)) method :

```
private void animateAlpha(View view, float alphaBy, long duration) {
    view.animate()
        .alphaBy(alphaBy)
        .setDuration(duration); // milliseconds
}
```

Assuming your first TextView's alpha value is 0.9f, and y the second is 0.1f you could call the method twice, where you can also adjust the duration of the animation like this:

```
animateAlpha(textView1, -0.8f, 1000);
animateAlpha(textView2, 0.8f, 1000);
```

As for general animations I can recommend ViewPropertyAnimator, as it is very readable and complex animations are possible in a single line of code. As for your expand and collapse animation you could also look into the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator), and for example use the [scaleXBy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#scaleXBy(float)) and the scaleYBy method.